# How to install Laravel 4 packages on Windows

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

Is it me or are resources on this sparse for absolute n00bs that have never worked with PHP Frameworks.

I have managed to install Laravel 4 on my Windows via WAMP.

I would now like to install [this package](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter-l4) on my Laravel installation.

How do I do that? The docs on github say:

> Add **thujohn/twitter** to **composer.json**.
>
> *"thujohn/twitter": "dev-master"*

It doesn't say where to add it though, that file has many other nested elements in it. Also, the documentation then says:

> Run **composer update** to pull down the latest version of Twitter.

Where do I type and run that command? Is it in Windows CMD? Do I have to navigate anywhere first? All the above might be obvious to the experienced person, but to n00bs it isn't at all.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Further down the docs, it also says to run:

> Run **php artisan config:publish thujohn/twitter** and modify the config file with your own informations.

This too is to be typed and ran in the command prompt in the directory where the `composer.json` file sits.

Comment: Run composer update in the the root folder in the command propt and "thujohn/twitter": "dev-master" you need to put in the "Required" section

Comment: On Windows we don't have a Terminal. I'm guessing you mean the Command Prompt. Do I have to navigate anywhere first?

Comment: In the directory of your Project

Comment: Upvoted, because this is exactly how I felt when I begun programming in different frameworks. I didn't have clue what most of the stuff means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the line `"thujohn/twitter": "dev-master"` to the require section like so;

```
"require" : {
    "thujohn/twitter": "dev-master"
}
```

If you have other packages above be sure to put a comma at the end of the last line.

Within the folder in which your composer.json and other files are, hold `shift` and click Open command prompt here. (Or something along them lines). Then type and run the command `composer update`. And your done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe) installed on your system, once that's done you can open a command prompt, and run `composer` anywhere you want.

So to install that package, edit your `composer.json` file that's in your Laravel root directory, then open a command prompt, `cd` to that directory and run the necessary composer commands there.